# Strange thing in getting objects from background

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have query

```
private var query = PFQuery(className: "Ideas")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: [AnyObject]?, error) -> Void in
    var objects = data as! [PFObject]
    for tmp in objects {
        self.ideas.insert(CIdea(parseObject: tmp), atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

I try to get array of `PFObject` from background, instance from it `CIdea` and insert in `CIdea` array, but got issue that found `nil` in

`var objects = data as! [PFObject]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if let objects = Object as? [PFObject]{
        for tmp in objects {
        self.ideas.insert(CIdea(parseObject: tmp), atIndex: 0)
    }
 }
```

Comment: this code just will not be performed, cause in query I get `nil`

Comment: I tried `query.findObjectsInBackground( )` and it returned  `nil `

Comment: Do you have data on parse in `class "Ideas"`

Comment: Yes, I added some initial data to parse

Comment: check your class name it cannot return nil if you have data in parse

Comment: I've copy-pasted class name from Parse, but it still returns  `nil `

Comment: where are you calling this method

Comment: In the init of model class.

Comment: I've just tried to get data in ViewDidLoad() and it works.